# Chart.JS Multiline Chart with unknown numbers of Lines from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array, chart.js

I try do to a Multi - Linechart with chart.js. I have a json dataset from a database. The number of dataset can be different. Here is a example (x can be more) with JSON Data.

```
[{"name":"name1","jan":4067.5,"feb":1647,
"mrz":1375,"apr":10191,"mai":0,"jun":28679,"jul":59502},
{"name":"name2","jan":47548,"feb":63280.5,
"mrz":51640.26,"apr":75029,"mai":41137,"jun":89114.26,"jul":77332},
{"name":"name3","jan":38099,"feb":55023.5,
"mrz":62668,"apr":39482,"mai":44193.3,"jun":52826.5,"jul":77072},
{"name":"namex","jan":34930.5,"feb":36831.5,
"mrz":24391,"apr":35051,"mai":38038,"jun":12700,"jul":51080}]
```

I have abbreviated the example, in reality it is until December.

I try to do a chart with a line for every name. The X-axis should be the months of January to December and the Y-axis sales.

34/5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, your dataset will get dynamically updated.

You can just change your dataset then call the `update()` function.

For example:

First initialize your chart with all the data using:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("barChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "name 1",
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(225,0,0,0.4)",
      borderColor: "red",
      borderCapStyle: 'square',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: "black",
      pointBackgroundColor: "white",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "yellow",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "brown",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, ,60,55,30,78]
    }, {
      label: "name 2",
      fill: true,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(167,105,0,0.4)",
      borderColor: "rgb(167, 105, 0)",
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: "white",
      pointBackgroundColor: "black",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "brown",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "yellow",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [10, 20, 60, 95, 64, 78, 90,,70,40,70,89]
    }

  ]
};

var options = {
  scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     labelString: 'Moola',
                     fontSize: 20 
                  }
            }]            
        }  
};

// Chart declaration:
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

Then if you later want to update your data, you can just:

```
myBarChart.data.datasets = [{
      label: "name 3",
      fill: true,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(167,105,0,0.4)",
      borderColor: "rgb(167, 105, 0)",
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: "white",
      pointBackgroundColor: "black",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "brown",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "yellow",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [10, 20, 60, 95, 64, 78, 90,,70,40,70,89]
    },
    ...............
];

myBarChart.update();
```

Also, you will need to format your data in a way that can be used with the charts.
Format your data so that you can create a proper dataset.

Comment: Thanks for helping,

No, that was not how it was meant. 


I have a SQL query which can contain 5 to 10 lines. The amount of lines is fixed on the call.

I want a line in the diagram for each name, the data should come from the Json and are fixed after the query. But it can be tomorrow, a new name comes to it, but it is in the JSON data in it.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details. I don't understand what you are trying to say. Your JSON data will update after some time. right?

Comment: Right, my JSON data can change. The names are employees. And new ones can come in or leave us. I want a line for every employee. I changed my JSON and created the data at JSFiddle. Except for one mistake, I think I'm very close to the solution :-). [link](https://jsfiddle.net/waldi969/m4bktrgx/33/)

Comment: Here I, have made some changes. I have created the chart using the JSON array. Here is the link [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wncuzey7/3/).

Comment: Thanks for your work. It works perfectly in JSFiddle. But on my own webserver I have the following error message:

`Chart.bundle.js:6904 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.acquireContext (Chart.bundle.js:6904)
    at Chart.construct (Chart.bundle.js:8423)
    at new Chart (Chart.bundle.js:8410)
    at appdata16_1.js:60
acquireContext @ Chart.bundle.js:6904
construct @ Chart.bundle.js:8423
Chart @ Chart.bundle.js:8410
(anonymous) @ appdata16_1.js:60`

Comment: I can't tell much without looking at your code, but I guess the problem could be that when your code executes, the canvas has not been created yet. You should wrap your code inside a function and assign that function to window.onload event.

`window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
......
}`

Comment: Can you please upvote and accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: I think, i have done this. What should i do?

`Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.`

Comment: No need to do anything now. Thanks